# Unary Ampersand Operator and passing procs as arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble understanding this code below.

I get the idea of Unary Ampersand Operator and passing procs as arguments to methods. But I really can't wrap my head around passing `self` to the `language.call`. I understand it like this: we're passing `self` as an argument to the proc/block language. It doesn't make any sense to me. Can someone please explain? :)

```
class Translator    
  def speak &language
    language.call(self)    
  end

  protected

  def french
    'bon jour'  
  end

  def spanish
    'hola'   
  end

  def turkey
    'gobble'   
  end

  def method_missing(*args)
    'awkward silence'
  end 
end
```

We're using it with:

```
translator.speak(&:spanish)
```

Comment: To get you started, you might want to see [this answer about `&:symbol`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut) syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what happened when pass a method to iterator method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365452/what-happened-when-pass-a-method-to-iterator-method)

Comment: What is `translator`?

Comment: translator is simply Translator.new

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This example beautifully ties together multiple Ruby concepts. Because of that, I will try to explain all of them.

1. Blocks

Methods in Ruby can accept blocks (pieces of code) in elegant matter:

```
def run_code
  yield
end

run_code { puts 42 } # => prints 42
```

2. Procs are similar to blocks, but they are actual addressable objects:

```
deep_thought = proc { puts 42 }
deep_thought.call # => prints 42
```

3. You can turn a proc into a block when calling a method with the `&` operator:

```
def run_code
  yield
end

deep_thought = proc { puts 42 }
run_code(&deep_thought) # => prints 42
```

4. Procs and blocks can accept arguments:

```
def reveal_answer
  yield 5_000
end

deep_thought = proc do |years_elapsed|
  years_elapsed >= 7_500_000 ? 42 : 'Still processing'
end

reveal_answer(&deep_thought) # => 'Still processing'
```

5. You can turn a block into proc using `&` in the method signature:

```
def inspector(&block)
  puts block.is_a?(Proc)
  puts block.call
end

inspector { puts 42 } # => prints true and 42
inspector(&proc { puts 42 }) # => the same
```

6. `Symbol#to_proc` creates a proc that calls methods with the same name on the object:

```
class Dummy
  def talk
    'wooooot'
  end
end

:talk.to_proc.call(Dummy.new) # => "wooooot"
```

In other words,

```
:bar.to_proc.call(foo)
```

is pretty much equivalent to

```
foo.bar
```

7. `BasicObject#method_missing`:

When you try to call a method on an object, Ruby traverses it's ancestor chain, searching for a method with that name. How the chain is constructed is a different topic, lengthy enough for another day, the important thing is that if the method is not found til the very bottom (`BasicObject`), a second search is performed on the same chain - this time for a method called `method_missing`. It gets passed as arguments the name of the original method plus any argument it received:

```
class MindlessParrot
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    "You caldt #{method_name} with #{args} on me, argh!"
  end
end

MindlessParrot.new.foo          # => "You caldt foo with [] on me, argh!"
MindlessParrot.new.bar :baz, 42 # => "You caldt bar with [:baz, 42] on me, argh!"
```

---

So what does all this mean in our specific case? Lets assume for a second there was no `protected`.

```
translator.speak(&:spanish)
```

calls the method `Translator#speak` with `:spanish` converted to block.

`Translator#speak` takes that block and transforms it to a proc, named `language`, and calls it, passing `self` as argument.

`self` is an instance of `Translator`, therefore, it has the methods `speak`, `french`, `spanish`, `turkey` and `method_missing`.

And so:

```
Translator.new.speak(&:spanish)
```

is equivalent to:

```
:spanish.to_proc.call(Translator.new)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Translator.new.spanish
```

giving us `"hola"`.

---

Now, taking the `protected` back, all the language methods of our `translator` object are still present, but they can not be directly accessed by outsiders.

Just as you can't call

```
Translator.new.spanish
```

and expect `"hola"` back, you can't call

```
Translator.new.speak(&:spanish)
```

And since the method is not directly accessible, it is considered not found and `method_missing` is called, thus giving us `"awkward silence"`.

Comment: Excellent, excellent writeup.  One thing: I was under the impression that the &:name syntax actually used symbol#to_proc to create a Proc directly without creating an intermediate block.  You say that it "calls the method Translator#speak with :spanish converted to block".  Can you clarify?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, What happens is `&something` when calling a method will call `something`'s `to_proc` method and then convert that proc to block. This can be verified by creating your own class with `to_proc` method. If the receiving method has `&something` in the signature, this block is converted back to proc. This can be verified by inspecting the `ObjectSpace` and is a cause for slowdown (always use `yield` if you don't really need a reference to the actual proc).

Comment: Thank you sir, much appreciated! I just want to make sure I get it right - passing self to the block in this example is just equivalent to invoking language on specific instance of an object?

Comment: @Jes, on the same instance (`translator`), yes.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing - I thought it is used only with iterators (at least I've seen examples with Enumerable methods such as each and map). So it can be used with any method?

Comment: @Jes, yep, any method as seen in the examples above. There are no actual iterators (in the sense you would talk about them in Java/C++ etc.), it's just that methods like `map` pick every individual element in the `Enumerable` and pass it as an argument to the block that was provided.