# A spelling, expected to be equivalent, causes error. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

I'm reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut), where it says, that the calls

```
something {|i| i.foo }
something(&:foo)
```

are equivalent.

Now I was trying to refactor my model named `AdminUser` according to this pattern and replaced

```
after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }
```

with

```
after_create(&:send_reset_password_instructions)
```

, but when I'm running my migration, which contains the lines

```
def migrate(direction)
  super
  # Create a default user
  AdminUser.create!(email: 'a@b.de', password: 'very_clever', password_confirmation: 'very_clever') if direction == :up
end
```

it gives me the error

```
ArgumentError: no receiver given
```

pointing to the line `AdminUser.create!...`.

Can anyone tell me what goes wrong here?

Comment: I see no reason that you cannot replace `after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }` with the shorter form, so I'd look elsewhere for the problem. You're thinking, "but it worked before I made the change", but I'd double-check that you made no other changes, perhaps inadvertently.

Comment: better yet, why not just do `after_create :send_reset_password_instructions`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but it interested me quite a bit causing me to do some research of my own. I don't have a corrected code answer for you, but in looking around I believe this post [what happened when pass a method to iterator method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365452/what-happened-when-pass-a-method-to-iterator-method) is very closely related and will most likely answer your question of "what's going wrong here?"

Basically because you're now passing it a proc with the refactored code it's expecting a specific argument that your `AdminUser` is no longer passing it and causing the error of it not having a receiver.

That being said, I'm sure you have your reasons of setting up your code the way you do, but based on the implied idea of what you're doing and the context I would agree with @photoionized with using
`after_create :send_reset_password_instructions` as it's clear, concise and (most likely) has your desired outcome.